# How to parse KEGG module (md:) flat files into Pandas DataFrame in Python? (i.e., parse text by section reading line-by-line only once)

Tags: python, database, rest, parsing, bioinformatics

I'm trying to write a parser for this type of file but it's proven to a bit more tricky than I thought.  If this was a few years ago, I would just read the file multiple times but now I think about efficiency and that is no bueno as there must be a better way.

**How can I parse each section while reading the file line-by-line only once?**

My attempt was by setting a variable that is changed depending on the section.  This started working but as you can see it gets messed up on the second grouping (e.g. REACTION).  I feel like `while` loops might be the answer but I am not sure how to implement that in this context.

```
from io import StringIO
f = StringIO(
"""
ENTRY       M00001            Pathway   Module
NAME        Glycolysis (Embden-Meyerhof pathway), glucose => pyruvate
DEFINITION  (K00844,K12407,K00845,K00886,K08074,K00918) (K01810,K06859,K13810,K15916) (K00850,K16370,K21071,K00918) (K01623,K01624,K11645,K16305,K16306) K01803 ((K00134,K00150) K00927,K11389) (K01834,K15633,K15634,K15635) K01689 (K00873,K12406)
ORTHOLOGY   K00844,K12407,K00845  hexokinase/glucokinase [EC:2.7.1.1 2.7.1.2] [RN:R01786]
            K00886  polyphosphate glucokinase [EC:2.7.1.63] [RN:R02189]
            K08074,K00918  ADP-dependent glucokinase [EC:2.7.1.147] [RN:R09085]
            K01810,K06859,K13810,K15916  glucose-6-phosphate isomerase [EC:5.3.1.9] [RN:R02740]
            K00850,K16370,K21071  6-phosphofructokinase [EC:2.7.1.11] [RN:R04779]
            K00918  ADP-dependent phosphofructokinase [EC:2.7.1.146] [RN:R09084]
            K01623,K01624,K11645,K16305,K16306  fructose-bisphosphate aldolase [EC:4.1.2.13] [RN:R01070]
            K01803  triosephosphate isomerase [EC:5.3.1.1] [RN:R01015]
            K00134,K00150  glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate dehydrogenase [EC:1.2.1.12 1.2.1.59] [RN:R01061 R01063]
            K00927  phosphoglycerate kinase [EC:2.7.2.3] [RN:R01512]
            K11389  glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate dehydrogenase (ferredoxin) [EC:1.2.7.6] [RN:R07159]
            K01834,K15633,K15634,K15635  phosphoglycerate mutase [EC:5.4.2.11 5.4.2.12] [RN:R01518]
            K01689  enolase [EC:4.2.1.11] [RN:R00658]
            K00873,K12406  pyruvate kinase [EC:2.7.1.40] [RN:R00200]
CLASS       Pathway modules; Carbohydrate metabolism; Central carbohydrate metabolism
PATHWAY     map00010  Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis
            map01200  Carbon metabolism
            map01100  Metabolic pathways
REACTION    R01786,R02189,R09085  C00267 -> C00668
            R02740  C00668 -> C05345
            R04779,R09084  C05345 -> C05378
            R01070  C05378 -> C00111 + C00118
            R01015  C00111 -> C00118
            R01061,R01063  C00118 -> C00236
            R01512  C00236 -> C00197
            R07159  C00118 -> C00197
            R01518  C00197 -> C00631
            R00658  C00631 -> C00074
            R00200  C00074 -> C00022
COMPOUND    C00267  alpha-D-Glucose
            C00668  alpha-D-Glucose 6-phosphate
            C05345  beta-D-Fructose 6-phosphate
            C05378  beta-D-Fructose 1,6-bisphosphate
            C00111  Glycerone phosphate
            C00118  D-Glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate
            C00236  3-Phospho-D-glyceroyl phosphate
            C00197  3-Phospho-D-glycerate
            C00631  2-Phospho-D-glycerate
            C00074  Phosphoenolpyruvate
            C00022  Pyruvate
///
"""
)


kegg_definition = None
kegg_orthology = list()
kegg_ortholog_set = set()
kegg_class = None
kegg_pathways = list()
kegg_pathway_set = set()
kegg_reactions = list()
kegg_reaction_set = set()
kegg_compounds = list()
kegg_compound_set = set()

# Read KEGG module text
parsing = None
for line_level_1 in f:
    line_level_1 = line_level_1.strip()
    if not line_level_1.startswith("/"):
        # Get orthologs
        if line_level_1.startswith("DEFINITION"):
            kegg_definition = line_level_1.replace("DEFINITION","").strip()
            kegg_ortholog_set = str(kegg_definition)
            for character in list("(+ -)"):
                kegg_ortholog_set.replace(character, ",")
            kegg_ortholog_set = set(filter(bool, kegg_ortholog_set.split(",")))
            parsing = "ORTHOLOGY"
        if parsing == "ORTHOLOGY":
            ko_annot = line_level_1.replace("DEFINITION","").strip()
            kegg_orthology.append(ko_annot)
        # Get class
        if line_level_1.startswith("CLASS"):
    #         parsing = None
            kegg_class = line_level_1.replace("CLASS","").strip().split("; ")
        # Get pathways
        if line_level_1.startswith("PATHWAY"):
            parsing = "PATHWAY"
        if parsing == "PATHWAY":
            kegg_pathway = line_level_1.replace("PATHWAY","").strip().split("; ")
            kegg_pathways.append(kegg_pathway)
        # Get reactions
        if line_level_1.startswith("REACTION"):
            parsing = "REACTION"
        if parsing == "REACTION":
            kegg_reaction = line_level_1.replace("REACTION","").strip().split("; ")
            kegg_reactions.append(kegg_reaction)
        # Get compounds
        if line_level_1.startswith("COMPOUND"):
            parsing = "COMPOUND"
        if parsing == "COMPOUND":
            kegg_compound = line_level_1.replace("COMPOUND","").strip().split("; ")
            kegg_compounds.append(kegg_compound)
            
kegg_pathways
# [['map00010  Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis'],
#  ['map01200  Carbon metabolism'],
#  ['map01100  Metabolic pathways'],
#  ['REACTION    R01786,R02189,R09085  C00267 -> C00668']]
```

Comment: You probably should just use a parsing library.

Comment: Which one and in what way?

Comment: For example pyparsing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776185/advice-on-python-parser-generators

Comment: Concerning your current issue: you wrote "As you can see it gets messed up [in] REACTION". How should we see that? What did you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: It's always frustrating to answer questions of the form "I want to parse a file like this", where "like this" is explained with a single example. "Like this" says nothing about the other possible options (more keywords/sections/attributes or whatever those are? maybe some are optional? Is the order fixed? Is whitespace strict? (Are 2 spaces different from 1 space)? somewhat significant? only matters to human readers? And a whole bunch more... If you have a specific question about parsing, provide enough details so that the precise file format is not needed. ...

Comment: If you do have a precise specification, it should cost little to include a link in the question, in case some detail in the spec happens to be important. (This isn't an offer to handle out-of-scope questions like write-my-project (too broad) or gimme-a-tool (too opinionated).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case this helps anyone in the future.  Here's the parser I made.  However, if you are looking to calculate module completion ratios from a group of orthologs (e.g. a metagenome assembled genome or bin) then you need to take into consideration the [logicals](https://bmcgenomics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2164-13-699) in the KEGG definition and the fact that some modules are bifurcated...in which you should probably use some of the code in [MicrobeAnnotator](https://github.com/cruizperez/MicrobeAnnotator/issues/9)

```
import datetime
from Bio.KEGG.REST import kegg_list, kegg_get

# Parse KEGG Module
def parse_kegg_module(module_file):
    """
    
    Example of a KEGG REST module file:
    
    ENTRY       M00001            Pathway   Module
    NAME        Glycolysis (Embden-Meyerhof pathway), glucose => pyruvate
    DEFINITION  (K00844,K12407,K00845,K00886,K08074,K00918) (K01810,K06859,K13810,K15916) (K00850,K16370,K21071,K00918) (K01623,K01624,K11645,K16305,K16306) K01803 ((K00134,K00150) K00927,K11389) (K01834,K15633,K15634,K15635) K01689 (K00873,K12406)
    ORTHOLOGY   K00844,K12407,K00845  hexokinase/glucokinase [EC:2.7.1.1 2.7.1.2] [RN:R01786]
                K00886  polyphosphate glucokinase [EC:2.7.1.63] [RN:R02189]
                K08074,K00918  ADP-dependent glucokinase [EC:2.7.1.147] [RN:R09085]
                K01810,K06859,K13810,K15916  glucose-6-phosphate isomerase [EC:5.3.1.9] [RN:R02740]
                K00850,K16370,K21071  6-phosphofructokinase [EC:2.7.1.11] [RN:R04779]
                K00918  ADP-dependent phosphofructokinase [EC:2.7.1.146] [RN:R09084]
                K01623,K01624,K11645,K16305,K16306  fructose-bisphosphate aldolase [EC:4.1.2.13] [RN:R01070]
                K01803  triosephosphate isomerase [EC:5.3.1.1] [RN:R01015]
                K00134,K00150  glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate dehydrogenase [EC:1.2.1.12 1.2.1.59] [RN:R01061 R01063]
                K00927  phosphoglycerate kinase [EC:2.7.2.3] [RN:R01512]
                K11389  glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate dehydrogenase (ferredoxin) [EC:1.2.7.6] [RN:R07159]
                K01834,K15633,K15634,K15635  phosphoglycerate mutase [EC:5.4.2.11 5.4.2.12] [RN:R01518]
                K01689  enolase [EC:4.2.1.11] [RN:R00658]
                K00873,K12406  pyruvate kinase [EC:2.7.1.40] [RN:R00200]
    CLASS       Pathway modules; Carbohydrate metabolism; Central carbohydrate metabolism
    PATHWAY     map00010  Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis
                map01200  Carbon metabolism
                map01100  Metabolic pathways
    REACTION    R01786,R02189,R09085  C00267 -> C00668
                R02740  C00668 -> C05345
                R04779,R09084  C05345 -> C05378
                R01070  C05378 -> C00111 + C00118
                R01015  C00111 -> C00118
                R01061,R01063  C00118 -> C00236
                R01512  C00236 -> C00197
                R07159  C00118 -> C00197
                R01518  C00197 -> C00631
                R00658  C00631 -> C00074
                R00200  C00074 -> C00022
    COMPOUND    C00267  alpha-D-Glucose
                C00668  alpha-D-Glucose 6-phosphate
                C05345  beta-D-Fructose 6-phosphate
                C05378  beta-D-Fructose 1,6-bisphosphate
                C00111  Glycerone phosphate
                C00118  D-Glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate
                C00236  3-Phospho-D-glyceroyl phosphate
                C00197  3-Phospho-D-glycerate
                C00631  2-Phospho-D-glycerate
                C00074  Phosphoenolpyruvate
                C00022  Pyruvate
    ///
    """

    kegg_module = None
    kegg_name = None
    kegg_definition = None
    kegg_orthology = list()
    kegg_ortholog_set = set()
    kegg_classes = list()
    kegg_pathways = list()
    kegg_pathway_set = set()
    kegg_reactions = list()
    kegg_reaction_set = set()
    kegg_compounds = list()
    kegg_compound_set = set()

    # Read KEGG module text
    parsing = None
    for line in module_file:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line.startswith("/"):
            if not line.startswith(" "):
                first_word = line.split(" ")[0]
                if first_word.isupper() and first_word.isalpha():
                    parsing = first_word
            if parsing == "ENTRY":
                kegg_module = list(filter(bool, line.split(" ")))[1]
            if parsing == "NAME":
                kegg_name = line.replace(parsing, "").strip()
                parsing = None
            if parsing == "DEFINITION":
                kegg_definition = line.replace(parsing,"").strip()
                kegg_ortholog_set = str(kegg_definition)
                for character in list("(+ -)"):
                    kegg_ortholog_set = kegg_ortholog_set.replace(character, ",")
                kegg_ortholog_set = set(filter(bool, kegg_ortholog_set.split(",")))
            if parsing == "ORTHOLOGY":
                kegg_orthology.append(line.replace(parsing,"").strip())
            if parsing == "CLASS":
                kegg_classes = line.replace(parsing,"").strip().split("; ")
            if parsing == "PATHWAY":
                kegg_pathway = line.replace(parsing,"").strip()
                kegg_pathways.append(kegg_pathway)
                id_pathway = kegg_pathway.split(" ")[0]
                kegg_pathway_set.add(id_pathway)
            if parsing == "REACTION":
                kegg_reaction = line.replace(parsing,"").strip()
                kegg_reactions.append(kegg_reaction)
                for id_reaction in kegg_reaction.split(" ")[0].split(","):
                    kegg_reaction_set.add(id_reaction)
            if parsing == "COMPOUND":
                kegg_compound = line.replace(parsing,"").strip()
                id_compound = kegg_compound.split(" ")[0]
                kegg_compounds.append(kegg_compound)
                kegg_compound_set.add(id_compound)

    module_info = pd.Series(
        data = OrderedDict([
            ("NAME",kegg_name),
            ("DEFINITION",kegg_definition),
            ("ORTHOLOGY",kegg_orthology),
            ("ORTHOLOGY_SET",kegg_ortholog_set),
            ("CLASS",kegg_classes),
            ("PATHWAY",kegg_pathways),
            ("PATHWAY_SET",kegg_pathway_set),
            ("REACTION",kegg_reactions),
            ("REACTION_SET",kegg_reaction_set),
            ("COMPOUND",kegg_compounds),
            ("COMPOUND_SET",kegg_compound_set),
        ]),
        name=kegg_module,
    )
            
    return module_info


def get_kegg_modules(expand_nested_modules=True):
    results = list()
    for line in list(kegg_list("module")):
        line = line.strip()
        module, name = line.split("\t")
        prefix, id_module = module.split(":")
        module_file = kegg_get(module)
        module_info = parse_kegg_module(module_file)
        results.append(module_info)
    df = pd.DataFrame(results)
    df.index.name = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("Accessed: %Y-%m-%d @ %H:%M")
    
    # Expand nested modules
    if expand_nested_modules:
        for id_module, row in df.iterrows():
            kegg_orthology_set = row["ORTHOLOGY_SET"]
            expanded = set()
            for x in kegg_orthology_set:
                if x.startswith("K"):
                    expanded.add(x)
                if x.startswith("M"):
                    for id_ko in df.loc[x,"ORTHOLOGY_SET"]:
                        expanded.add(id_ko)
            df.loc[id_module, "ORTHOLOGY_SET"] = expanded
    return df
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you don't check for REACTION until after you've already gathered the line into PATHWAY.  Do all of your "next section?" checking before you start using the "parsing" value:

```
# Read KEGG module text
parsing = None
for line_level_1 in f:
    line_level_1 = line_level_1.strip()
    if not line_level_1.startswith("/"):
        if line_level_1.startswith("DEFINITION"):
            kegg_definition = line_level_1.replace("DEFINITION","").strip()
            kegg_ortholog_set = str(kegg_definition)
            for character in list("(+ -)"):
                kegg_ortholog_set.replace(character, ",")
            kegg_ortholog_set = set(filter(bool, kegg_ortholog_set.split(",")))
        elif line_level_1.startswith("CLASS"):
            kegg_class = line_level_1.replace("CLASS","").strip().split("; ")
        elif line_level_1.startswith("ORTHOLOGY"):
            parsing = "ORTHOLOGY"
        elif line_level_1.startswith("PATHWAY"):
            parsing = "PATHWAY"
        elif line_level_1.startswith("REACTION"):
            parsing = "REACTION"
        elif line_level_1.startswith("COMPOUND"):
            parsing = "COMPOUND"
        
        if parsing == "ORTHOLOGY":
            ko_annot = line_level_1.replace("DEFINITION","").strip()
            kegg_orthology.append(ko_annot)
        elif parsing == "PATHWAY":
        # Get pathways
            kegg_pathway = line_level_1.replace("PATHWAY","").strip().split("; ")
            kegg_pathways.append(kegg_pathway)
        # Get reactions
        elif parsing == "REACTION":
            kegg_reaction = line_level_1.replace("REACTION","").strip().split("; ")
            kegg_reactions.append(kegg_reaction)
        # Get compounds
        elif parsing == "COMPOUND":
            kegg_compound = line_level_1.replace("COMPOUND","").strip().split("; ")
            kegg_compounds.append(kegg_compound)
            
print(kegg_pathways)
```